# The selected text in my textbox is not what I am expecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using an autocomplete future on my website to retrieve selected data to a dropdown list. In that dropdown I am showing a name and a function. But when I am selecting an item from the dropdown list the value shown in the textbox is not what I am expecting as shown below where I am selecting "Antonio Moreno" but the selected value shows as Antonio Moreno_Owner which is the value I am parsing from the database. What I want is that when selecting an item only the names shows up. I tried adding "                $("[id$=txtSearch]").val(i.item.label.split('_')[0]);" under select: function (e, i) { but it didn't work. (The database referenced in that sample is Northwind database)

[image]

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery- 
     ui.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" 
     href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" />
 <style type="text/css">
.labelText {
    color: red;
    float: left;
    font-family: Courier New;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.valueText {
    float: right;
    background-color: aqua;
    font-family: Courier New;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.dvDetails {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 235px;
    height: 30px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/GetCustomers") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("[id$=hfCustomerId]").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var div = $("<li>")
            .append("<a class='dvDetails'><span class='labelText'>" + item.label.split('_')[0] +
                "</span><span class='valueText'>(" + item.label.split('_')[1] + ")</span></a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        return div;
    };;
});
</script>
 Enter search term:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />
```

And the code on the server is

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetCustomers(prefix As String) As String()
    Dim customers As New List(Of String)()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "select ContactName, CustomerId,ContactTitle from Customers where ContactName like @SearchText + '%'"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix)
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    customers.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr("ContactName") & "_" & sdr("ContactTitle"), sdr("CustomerId")))
                End While
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Return customers.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: This look wrong `label: item.split('-')[0]` you split on a dash and take the first part, but this line `String.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr("ContactName") & "_" & sdr("ContactTitle"), sdr("CustomerId"))` has the first part as the contact underscore title. So maybe `label: item.split('_')[0]`? (not tested)